# Y a t-il un équivalent en français de l'idée de « talk radio » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

En Amérique du Nord, il y a plusieurs formats de stations de radio et je cherche une expression de langue française pour le format dit de « *[talk radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_radio)* ». Une « *talk radio* » est une station de radio dont la programmation est composée exclusivement « d'émissions de discussions », d'émissions « parlées ». L'expression « radio généraliste » ne marche pas car une radio généraliste (prenons le cas de France Inter, en France) peut posséder des émissions musicales. Une *talk radio* n'a pas de programmation musicale.

Il n'y a peut-être aucun équivalent en français, mais j'espérais que les québécois avaient peut-être une expression de leur cru étant donné que le format « *talk radio* » était présent au Canada. J'ai déjà vu mentionné le terme de « radio parlée » mais il me paraît, de premier abord, un peu [capillotracté](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/capillotract%C3%A9) et je me demandais s'il n'y avait pas un terme français nord-américain plus courant.

[Merki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lie_Semoun).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Le grand dictionnaire terminologique](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/) de l'Office québécois de la langue française donne deux termes français pour *talk radio*, selon le type de programmation en question :

> 1. **[Radio interactive](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8395974)**
>      Formule de programmation radiophonique constituée de tribunes téléphoniques ou d'émissions de variétés où le public est appelé à intervenir directement au moyen du téléphone.
> 2. **[Radio parlée](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8395975)**
>      Radio dont le programme est constitué uniquement d'émissions parlées.

La paternité de ces deux fiches est attribuée à Radio-Canada, qui, pendant de nombreuses années (j'ignore si c'est encore le cas), offrait ce genre de programmation sur les ondes d'une de ses chaînes radio.

D'un autre côté, [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra), la banque de données terminologiques et linguistiques du gouvernement du Canada, contient également une fiche sur le sujet :

> **[Radio à prépondérance verbale](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=TALK%20RADIO)**
>     **Def** – Format radiophonique qui met principalement l'accent sur des conversations entre un animateur à statut de vedette ou une personnalité, et les auditeurs.
>
> **Obs** – Il n'existe pas de traduction officielle pour la « talk radio », y mêlant aussi une touche de divertissement pouvant parfois aller jusqu'à la provocation. C'est pourquoi, nous n'avons pas retenu l'équivalent « radio interactive ».

Le Conseil de la radiodiffusion et des télécommunications canadiennes utilise le terme « radio à prépondérance verbale » tandis que les organisations québécoises utilisent vraisemblablement l'un des deux autres termes.

Answer (score 4):

Le Grand Dictionnaire donne *radio interactive*, un terme très peu courant, et Termium donne *radio à prépondérance verbale*, ainsi que l'anglicisme *talk radio*. Autant dire qu'il n'y a pas vraiment de terme en usage, mais *radio à prépondérance verbale* est une traduction acceptable.

On parle souvent de *tribunes téléphoniques* pour ce qui est appelé un *call-in show* en anglais. Mais cela désigne un type de programmation plutôt qu'une catégorie de stations. Le synonyme *ligne ouverte* est fréquent mais déconseillé par ceux qui n'aiment pas les anglicismes.

On parle également souvent de *radio-poubelle* en parlant des stations connues pour les attitudes provocatrices adoptées par leurs animateurs. Québec, dit-on, est connue non seulement pour être la capitale du Québec, mais également celle des radios-poubelles.

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a que des périphrases sur *[linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais?query=talk%20radio%20station&source=english)*, car le format n'existe pas vraiment sur les ondes françaises.

Sans doute parce que la « radio parlote » n'intéresse pas grand monde ; les interviews, les échanges culturels ou journalistiques dépassent rarement les deux heures, et sont diffusés aux heures creuses lorsqu'ils ne constituent pas l'essentiel de l'actualité.

La télévision offre des *[chaînes dédiées aux infos](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCI)* (raccourci pour *informations diffusées par un medium*)

Comment: Je préfère largement le terme que vous venez d'inventé _radio parlote_ à celui de _radio à prépondérance verbale_. Eh ho!Termium?